# How does this FOR Loop Break when select is done

Tags: go

The following code waits for the 'results' channel to be empty
and then the DEFAULT branch breaks to Label DONE.

Now the question:  Why does this break the FOR LOOP?? It seems
that the FOR loop would continue to skip to DEFAULT and never
end.

WHAT IS BREAKING THE FOR LOOP.

The Output is as follows:

Break DONE

End For

---

```
...
DONE:
for {
    select { // Nonblocking
    case result := <-results:
        fmt.Printf("%s:%d:%s\n", result.filename, result.lino,
            result.line)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Break DONE")
        break DONE
    }
    fmt.Println("END Select")
}
fmt.Println("End For")
```

Answer (score 3):

`break DONE` is not the same as `goto DONE` in C or other languages. The label marks the for loop which `break DONE` statement will terminate when executed. It doesn't jump to `DONE` label, it terminates the for loop marked with the `DONE` label. Labeled breaks are very usefull when you want to break from nested loops or, like in your case, terminate loop from inside of select. Without a label break would only terminate select.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a label, it must be that of an enclosing "for", "switch", or "select" statement, and that is the one whose execution terminates.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements

The label in this example explicitly marks the "for" to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from the idea that you're going to block there on the first case. That's not what happens. You iterate the select options indefinitely taking the one available until you encounter the break. In this case, it would indicate there is nothing to receive from the `results` channel on your first iteration so it automatically falls into the default cause, prints `Break DONE` and you're done.

Comment: The break statement goes to DONE: and then would call the

Comment: for loop again.  How does DONE: escape the FOR Loop.  If you jump to DONE you execute a for {} block again.

Comment: @Godfather nah that is denoting the scope, it's not like a `goto` that's saying when I call break, break from the scope of `DONE` it's so you can nest loops and break statements. If you wrap the loop in yet another loop, and put a different label on it like `REALLYDONE` then you can see this because when you break `DONE` it will continue looping in the scope of `REALLYDONE`

Answer (score 0):

the break keyword used terminate the execution, when you debug this code, the default option will selected and then break keyword perform which stop the program. Program will not able go at DONE label